# The framework spawner server exited unexpectedly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, passenger

I'm having problems with my RoR application. Suddenly, after no changes or anything, I started getting the *The framework spawner server exited unexpectedly* exception.

I've tried searching for some information, but everything leads to dead end. I had the app running for about half a year with no problems, but I suddenly got this error.

I even tried rebooting the whole server but nothing seems to help. **What could possibly cause this?**

I'm using Phusion Passenger with Ruby Enterprise Edition 1.8.7.

[The app url is here](http://smallzoom.com/) if you want to see the whole stacktrace.

Answer (score 1):

One cause for this error message is that the server is out of memory.

Answer (score 0):

Check you Apache logs, it is highly probable that this is caused by some third party library on gem.
The stacktrace (and error) are pretty generic, so you need to dig a bit deeper to find the real cause.